# Remove all 'hidden' references to a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on SQL Server version 2019, and I'm a dev with decent SQL knowledge. Hope this explanation is sufficient to get some help.

So another dev mistakenly ran a vendor script on database A instead of database B. Part of what that script did was to create a table, I'll call it table ABC.

Problem is that the script failed when it ran on A, so ABC was not created on A. At least we all thought that was the case because expanding the `Tables` folder in SSMS showed no table ABC.

However the vendor app is no longer working when pointing to A. It says it can't find that table ABC!

Looks like the vendor app queries someplace else to get a list of tables in the database. I think it could be querying `sys.objects` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` because that table is listed there.

So my question is, how can I remove all of those references for ABC, wherever they may be located? Thanks much for any advice!

Comment: I would look at the script you deployed and see what changes it made, and visit each those objects. Or, possibly better, get your back up and transaction logs and restore to the point *before* you ran the script against the wrong database.

Comment: Also make sure to manually refresh the tables list in SSMS. It doesn't automatically update if you make changes.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but: Are you *sure* that the table shows up in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES but not in SSMS (even after refreshing the tables list)? This claim is so extraordinary that it might be worth "proving" it with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the table *did* exist. When the dev ran that script the table was not created as dbo.tablename , but as userid.tablename. So in SSMS, that table appeared last - after the 200+ plus dbo tables. Sorry for this post.

Thanks to all who responded so quickly though, I love stackoverflow for that reason.